# python script to run dynamic curl request

Tags: python, bash, curl

Python newb here, here's my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time
import datetime
import subprocess

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime(%Y%m%d)
```

My curl command:

```
curl -i -k -H -o <timestamp>.txt "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "appID:******" -H "appKey:*******" -X GET https://*****.com/csOpen/workplace/hr/v1/employees_s?type=EMP&location=******&term_from=<timestamp>
```

The dynamic aspect of this curl request comes from the python portion of my script. I need the output file to be the $currentTime.txt and i need the php variable $term_from to also be the timestamp.

So far ive tried invoking the curl command using

```
os.system('curl -i -k -H -o' + %st + '.txt "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "appID:arcsght_app" -H "appKey:*****" -X GET https://csopen.teamaol.com/csOpen/workplace/hr/v1/employees_s?type=EMP&location=Dulles&term_from=' + %st)
```

That didn't work, then i tried using

```
subprocess.call(<same curl command as above>)
```

and that didnt work.

Ive tried my curl command from bash and it works, and i can get my timestamp to show how i need it. I just cant figure out how to tie everything together. Before i posted this i did try to figure it out on my own, but this is my first real adventure into python so my knowledge of what works and what doesn't is pretty slim. Looking for help! Thanks.

Comment: I'd just use `$(date +"%Y%m%d")` in the `curl` invocation from shell and would not write any Python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_command = 'curl -i -k -H -o {timestamp}.txt "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "appID:******" -H "appKey:*******" -X GET https://*****.com/csOpen/workplace/hr/v1/employees_s?type=EMP&location=******&term_from={timestamp}'.format(timestamp=123456)

os.system(my_command)
```

should work fine ... Im not entirely sure why you want to do this in python... but this should allow you to no problem